# Facebook long-lived acces token with permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How get long-lived access token with permission user_posts???
I am using 
`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=xxx&
    client_secret=xxx&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}`

I need to user_posts permissionto gain access to Fb sharedposts, what you need to add to this URL

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the short-lived Acces Token via the normal login flow. Once you got it, you can exchange the short-lived one into a long-lived one.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: I have already received long-lived token.. but not user_posts permission

Comment: Well, then you should also write this in your question. If the `user_posts` permission is missing, it was not present in the short-lived one already. Is the user your getting the access token for an admin/test/developer of the app? If not, you need to got through Login Review to be able to request extended permission.

Comment: I need URL that returns me long-lived token with user_posts permission... using GRAPH API EXPLORER by checking on user_posts I can get token, but I need a URL for example:           
 [link](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=xxx&client_secret=xxx&fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}&scope=user_posts)

Comment: As I wrote, you first have to get a short-lived one containing the permission, and then EXCHANGE it to a long-lived one. It's all in the docs I linked. You CANNOT add permissions during the token exchange.